# Encender y apagar servidor mysql

Tags: java, mysql, consola

Quiero encender y apagar el servidor de mysql a través de java, esto solo es un ejercicio, utilicé el paquete org.apache.common.exec para correr el comando, el único problema es que solo lo puedo hacer a través del daemon con

```
sudo launchctl unload -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

(este para apagar el servidor)y quisiera ver si tienen algún comando para saber el estatus a través del daemon ya que con los demás comandos que he buscado me aparece un error de Pid.

Me habían dicho en otra pregunta que se podía saber el estatus del servidor a través del jdbc pero no encuentro dicha forma.

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza el siguiente código para ejecutar un comando (en este caso, apagar la base de datos) del SO desde java:

Linux

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("echo 'Password' | sudo -S service mysql stop");
//imprimes el password de root y lo lees de la salida con la opción -S
```

En windows sería algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec('"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqladmin" -u root shutdown');
```

Comment: y en osx para el echo como le hago?, intente el comando sudo -S service mysql stop y me dice command not found

Comment: En Windows, asumes que tienes la versión MySQL 5.7 instalada en la carpeta por defecto (error muy común).

Comment: @PaulAvalos en cualquier sistema operativo que trabajes, lo mejor es colocar la ruta de instalación de MySQL accesible mediante PATH. Luego, solo deberás ejecutar `mysql stop` y contar que tu programa en Java se ejecute con permisos de administrador.